# Ionic build windows phone

Tags: windows, cordova, ionic-framework

Hello I am a new developer in ionic framework. When I build windows app, it shows some errors in command prompt:

> E:\node\ionic\myApp>ionic build windows Running command:
>   E:\node\node.exe
>   E:\node\ionic\myApp\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js
>   E:\node\ionic\myApp add to body class: platform-windows Building
>   project:
>   E:\node\ionic\myApp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows.jsproj
>           Configuration : debug
>           Platform      : anycpu C:\Program Files\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2049,5):
>   error MSB3774: Could not find SDK "Microsoft.WinJS.2.0, Version=1.0".
>   [E:\node\ionic\myApp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows.jsproj]
>   Error: C:\Program Files\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed
>   with exit code 1

[image]

Plese help me

Comment: ionic is only for android and ios there is no way we can build it for windows application.

Comment: hey try to go through https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-ionic/ will get some idea at least.. hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11204

The solution I used was to boot Visual Studio, select "File > New Project >Windows > Windows8 > Install Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools, to download the Windows platform and tools.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova can't find winjs.2.0, so you need to install it using NuGet. I did it from Visual Studio Code 2015. Just go to ***Project > NuGet Package Management***, look for ***WinJS*** and install it.
I Can't upload a couple of screenshots I took because imgur is failing :/ I hope this explanation be enough!